# solubility of rare earth sulphides at different pH?

Tags: geochemistry, soil, rare-earth

Will rare earth sulfides in soil be more soluble in aqueous solutions with lower pH? How can I know whether these sulfides will dissolve better at low or high pH or will it not be affected?

Comment: How do you know that rare earth sulfides exist in your soil? Rare earth sulfides are extremely unstable in any earth environment and are very unlikely to form in the first place.

Comment: What oxidation-reduction state are you talking about?